# customized checkout option in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

Opencart payment methods are not supported to me, I have to build it in my own way. How do i customized it ? I don't have any idea of that. please someone can give me references it's fine. I trying to find. but still I could not find anything. Just want edit checkout and form submit to my own page with all the details that have in checkout .

Comment: Writing (I mean implementing) a payment gateway is not an easy task and it doesn't last 5 minutes, but may take 1-5 days to implement it completely. I doubt somebody here will do this for You and for free (usually payment gateways are a paid extensions). If You have a detailed specification from Your bank then using e.g. PayPal standard gateway already present in OpenCart, or any other operating with credit cards, should help You understand how payment gateways work and how to implement one on Your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best reference to study is **PayPal** opencart payment option **MVC**  or build with this reference [EBS payment gateway](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=6039)  its free extension study it also

Comment: ya its good. but do I edit this. My banker give me a few details to pass his page. this are the thing

Domain Url 
PGInstance Id 
Merchant Id 
Hash Key 

please help me

Comment: ya you need to modify it as per your requirements :)